# On Clicking a textbox in webpage text on page hide and then show ( flickers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a [website](http://echaractercount.com/character-count-online).

I have created a textbox, in which if I enter something, character count will be calculated via Jquery and get displayed in place of default character count.

I as soon as I click inside textbox everything on page kind of flickrs, No Idea why this is happening.

Many of you said, you are not able to reproduce it in your system. So I created a demo video
https://youtu.be/dRPXEA2MXGo

**Got it [resolved].**

Actually some chrome extension of mine was causing this. In incognito its working perfectly fine. Don't know what extension.

Comment: are you seeing this in a particular browser? . I am not able to see that in chrome

Comment: Yes, @karthick is right. Its not flickering with my Chrome even.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this in Opera or Firefox.

Comment: Same thing here, it works just fine, just a tip, use `onkeydown`instead of `onkeyup` for better tracking of the text length.

Comment: Thanks guys for replying, I have created a demo video to demonstrate the same. https://youtu.be/dRPXEA2MXGo  [update] its resolved now. updated in question. Thanks everyone.